# matlibplot generating plot confusion

Tags: python, gtk

I have the following code in separate GtkNotebook tabs and in different classes:

Plot no.1:

```
        self.vsm_fig = plt.figure(1)  
        subplots_adjust(bottom=0.20)
        self.vsm_canvas = FigureCanvas(self.vsm_fig)  
        self.vsm_chart_vbox.pack_start(self.vsm_canvas)
        self.vsm_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.vsm_canvas, self.vsm_chart_vbox)
        self.vsm_chart_vbox.pack_start(self.vsm_toolbar,False,False, 3)

        if len(results_vsm) >= 1: 
            for key,value in results_vsm.items():   
                plt.plot([0,1],[0,value], label=key) 
            plt.axis([0, 1, 0, 1])
            plt.legend()
            plt.show()
            self.vsm_canvas.draw()
```

Plot no.2:

```
        self.tf_idf_fig = plt.figure(2)     
        subplots_adjust(bottom=0.20)
        self.tf_idf_canvas = FigureCanvas(self.tf_idf_fig)  
        self.tf_idf_chart_vbox.pack_start(self.tf_idf_canvas)
        self.tf_idf_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.tf_idf_canvas, self.tf_idf_chart_vbox)
        self.tf_idf_chart_vbox.pack_start(self.tf_idf_toolbar,False,False, 3)

        if len(results_tfidf) >= 1:  
            plt.bar(*zip(*zip(count(), results_tfidf.values())))
            plt.title("TF IDF Chart")
            plt.xticks(*zip(*zip(count(), results_tfidf.keys())),rotation='vertical')
            plt.xlabel("Word")
            plt.ylabel("TF*IDF") 
            self.tf_idf_canvas.draw()
```

Why when i execute self.tf_idf_canvas.draw() of the second tab the plot is not generated. I tried to see with plt.show() what will happen and as a result the two plots were generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally not a good idea to mix the matplotlib classes provided by the backends and commands from pylab or pyplot. I had a lot of problems (memleaks etc.) with this, until I cleaned out all pylab calls and used just the class methods.

So add the imports you need like

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import\
    FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import\
    NavigationToolbar2GTKAgg as NavigationToolbar
```

etc., with whatever gtk backend you would like to use.

Then,

```
self.vsm_fig = Figure()
self.vsm_fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.20)
...
    plot = self.vsm_fig.add_subplot()
    plot.bar(*zip(*zip(count(), results_tfidf.values())))
    plot.set_title("TF IDF Chart")
    plot.set_xticks(*zip(*zip(count(), results_tfidf.keys())),rotation='vertical')
    plot.set_xlabel("Word")
    plot.set_ylabel("TF*IDF")
    self.vsm_canvas.show_now()
```

and accordingly with the second plot. Easiest way to make sure you forgot nothing is to just remove the pylab or pyplot import and see where the errors pop up.